# map.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: this.l.keys is not a function - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I came here searching some help if someone is having the same issue.

In my work, we have a web application that used Gmaps API version 3.34, but on may 15, this version was deleted for google and the maps stop working.

The app, takes automatically the new version 3.37, but the console throw the error:

> map.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: this.l.keys is not a function
>       at _.ll.Ab (map.js:56)
>       at ou (map.js:43)
>       at map.js:44

Some info about the app:

- The web app is old and uses JQuery v 1.9
- The maps use the js Gmap3 V 5.1.1

I tied some variations but nothing works:

- I used the Google Maps API versions 3.35, 3.36 and 3.37 with the same result.
- I update the JQuery tolatest version, but the web app stop working!!
- I update the Gmap3.js to latest version 7.2, but its structure and functions are different and doesn't work.

The console shows the error in the Gmap API line 56, at this point:

> ||a;g=this.C.ka;h=_.ua(this.l.keys());for(var
>   l=h.next();!l.done;l=h.next()){l=l.value;var
>   m=this.l.get(l),q=m.la,r=q.Y,v=new Bs(g,k,r),u=new
>   Bs(g,a,r),w=!this.J&&

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.l.keys is not a function

I apreciate some help

Thx

Comment: That error is deep in the Maps API. Check the call stack to find out where the call originated in your own logic to begin debugging it more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, one workaround is to remove 'center' from Maps options.

The same error is thrown when you try to setCenter().

Edit* : Turns out i was naming a method Map() and javascript already has a Map() function.

Check your code if you're not doing the same or the includes in the page.